# How much of the network stack do I have access to using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, tcp, data-link-layer

Looking at a representation of the TCP/IP stack, such as in this photo:
[image]

I would be interested (just out of curiosity) to try and read the layer 2 (data link) headers. Is this possible? I think that the `net` module only gives access to the transport layer packets. I see there is a `udp` module as well, but similarly I doubt that I could get data link-layer packet information from this.

Is the above correct? Am I correct in thinking that transport-layer packet data is made available to the JavaScript runtime via the v8/etc implementation and that lower level packet data (i.e. ethernet layer) is NOT exposed to Node.js runtimes?

Comment: Why the downvote? (I'm aware that I may have a complete and basic misunderstanding of this subject. if this is the case a comment as to why would be helpful, rather than just a downvote)

Comment: You can check table of contents to make sure what you can do and what you can't https://nodejs.org/api/ . Ethernet layer is obviously not exposed. I assume can access you whatever you wish with native addons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

node.js has access to `layer 3` and above. To capture `layer 2` packets you need to call external programs like [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org), or use modules that integrate these low level tools.

Wireshark has a [command line interface](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChCustCommandLine.html), you could invoke it from node using `child_process`.